# Why is this Hive QL expression failing?

Tags: java, hadoop, hex, string-formatting, endianness

This query is failing with a cryptic evaluation error:

```
select printf("%08x", reflect('java.lang.Integer', 'reverseBytes', mhash3('123', 0)));
```

(Here is the exception)

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Error evaluating printf('%08x', reflect('java.lang.Integer','reverseBytes',1))
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to reproduce consistently a Java implementation of a murmur3 hash hex value, which uses the hasher `getBytes` method, which returns them in a big endian format (and decimal numerals are written in little endian), thus the byte swapping in the integer.

Doing each part of the query separately works perfectly, it's mixing the printf and the reflect what fails... And only when the formatting is a number type, so this works:

```
select printf("%s", reflect('java.lang.Integer', 'reverseBytes', mhash3('123', 0)));
```

but this also fails

```
select printf("%d", reflect('java.lang.Integer', 'reverseBytes', mhash3('123', 0)));
```

and I've made sure that the result is a numeric type and not a string, since I can do arithmetic operations on it, like:

```
select printf("%s", 10 * reflect('java.lang.Integer', 'reverseBytes', mhash3('123', 0)));
```

So far I haven't needed to add any custom UDF's, so if there is a workaround for this I'd like to keep it that way.

Comment: There could be a wide gap between *"I can do arithmetic on it because somehow the JVM does some magic on goofy Object wrappers"* and *"it is a base numeric type that `printf` can handle directly"*. Did you try to `cast()` that evil `Integer` object into an old-fashion IEEE integer (a.k.a. `int`) before feeding it to `printf()` ?

Comment: To be precise, I mean the SQL syntax `cast(` _expr_ `as int)`

Comment: oh crap, that works! if you write that comment as an answer I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hive is basically a Java program that translates SQL-like data types and expressions into Java data types and Java/Hadoop expressions/jobs.
It's complicated enough in most cases. But if you throw a custom Java expression in the mix -- and that's what [`reflect()`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/ReflectUDF) is all about -- then you may well fall into an edge case.

In your specific issue, static [`java.lang.Integer.reverseBytes(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#reverseBytes-int-) is supposed to return a primitive type `int` value. But I am not sure how Hive handles generic integer values internally -- maybe with a `long`? maybe with a custom object type??
Anyway it looks like the return value cannot be fed *directly* into Hive `printf()` function as a numeric type. Maybe the `int` is cast to a `String` by default... maybe it would have worked with a `long` instead...

I see two possible workarounds:

1. wrap the call to `reflect()` in a sub-query, so that Hive does an implicit conversion to a Hive supported type (sub-query merged at compile-time, no extra MR step required) -- with the risk that the Hive type will still be `String`
   `select printf("%d", WTF) from (select reflect(.....) as WTF from ...) DUH`
2. require an explicit conversion to the Hive numeric type of your choice
    `select printf("%d", cast(reflect(.......) as int)) from ...`